# SQL sub query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The first table is `pre` and the second is `tran`. I want the `S_SSN` from `tran` where `no` and `Code` of transcript matches with `Code` and `no` in `pre`

Comment: Can you explain why `811111111` is your expected result

Comment: The result I get from the Inner query should all be there, if all the requirements match. Then only I should take it.

Comment: Student 415671238 has `D_Code = INFS` and `C_no = 600` also.

Comment: @wewesthemenace But that student does not have MATH 321 and INFS 501, as I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        t.Student_SSN,
        cc = COUNT(t.Student_SSN)
    FROM transcript t
    INNER JOIN prereq p
        ON t.C_no = p.P_no
        AND t.D_Code = p.P_Code
    WHERE
        p.D_Code = 'INFS' 
        AND p.C_no = 614
    GROUP BY t.Student_SSN
)
SELECT DISTINCT Student_SSN
FROM Cte
WHERE cc = (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM prereq  p
            WHERE p.D_Code = 'INFS' AND p.C_no = 614)
```

Comment: This does not give me the appropriate results.

Comment: Just add the appropriate filter.

Comment: The result I get from the Inner query should all be there, if all the requirements match. Then only I should take it.

Comment: Yes, I get the result, thanks. But is it possible to get the result without using count ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72722/discussion-between-user1989-and-wewesthemenace).